# Hbase doesn't recognize my java version

Tags: java, hadoop

I'm trying to install Hbase with this tutorial and I stepped upon something curious : hbase doesn't recognize my java version whereas Ubuntu 16.04 does.

```
mike@mike-thinks:~/hbase-1.2.6$ ./bin/start-hbase.sh
localhost: +======================================================================+
localhost: |                    Error: JAVA_HOME is not set                       |
localhost: +----------------------------------------------------------------------+
localhost: | Please download the latest Sun JDK from the Sun Java web site        |
localhost: |     > http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads        |
localhost: |                                                                      |
localhost: | HBase requires Java 1.7 or later.                                    |
localhost: +======================================================================+
starting master, logging to /home/mike/hbase-1.2.6/bin/../logs/hbase-mike-master-mike-thinks.out
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option PermSize=128m; support was removed in 8.0
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=128m; support was removed in 8.0
regionserver running as process 13688. Stop it first.

mike@mike-thinks:~/hbase-1.2.6$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_151"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)
```

It often happens that I have to do the following command : `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/`

Maybe I should edit `start-hbase.sh` to add it the java path, which I don't remember the command, but I can't find where I should put it.

---

I tried to set manually the `JAVA_HOME` variable, but it seems that it still don't find it even if the error message has changed

```
mike@mike-thinks:~/hbase-1.2.6/bin$ JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/

mike@mike-thinks:~/hbase-1.2.6/bin$ ./start-hbase.sh
/home/mike/hbase-1.2.6/bin/hbase: line 412: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin//bin/java: No such file or directory
/home/mike/hbase-1.2.6/bin/hbase: line 412: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin//bin/java: No such file or directory
starting master, logging to /home/mike/hbase-1.2.6/bin/../logs/hbase-mike-master-mike-thinks.out
/home/mike/hbase-1.2.6/bin/../bin/hbase: line 412: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin//bin/java: No such file or directory
regionserver running as process 13688. Stop it first.

mike@mike-thinks:~/hbase-1.2.6/bin$ sudo kill 13688
[sudo] password for mike: 

mike@mike-thinks:~/hbase-1.2.6/bin$ ./start-hbase.sh
/home/mike/hbase-1.2.6/bin/hbase: line 412: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin//bin/java: No such file or directory
/home/mike/hbase-1.2.6/bin/hbase: line 412: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin//bin/java: No such file or directory
starting master, logging to /home/mike/hbase-1.2.6/bin/../logs/hbase-mike-master-mike-thinks.out
/home/mike/hbase-1.2.6/bin/../bin/hbase: line 412: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin//bin/java: No such file or directory
starting regionserver, logging to /home/mike/hbase-1.2.6/bin/../logs/hbase-mike-1-regionserver-mike-thinks.out
/home/mike/hbase-1.2.6/bin/../bin/hbase: line 412: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin//bin/java: No such file or directory
```

---

After update I now have the following issues :

```
mike@mike-thinks:~/hbase-1.2.6/bin$ ./start-hbase.sh
/home/mike/hbase-1.2.6/bin/hbase: line 412: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java/bin/java: Not a directory
/home/mike/hbase-1.2.6/bin/hbase: line 412: exec: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java/bin/java: cannot execute: Not a directory
/home/mike/hbase-1.2.6/bin/hbase: line 412: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java/bin/java: Not a directory
/home/mike/hbase-1.2.6/bin/hbase: line 412: exec: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java/bin/java: cannot execute: Not a directory
starting master, logging to /home/mike/hbase-1.2.6/bin/../logs/hbase-mike-master-mike-thinks.out
/home/mike/hbase-1.2.6/bin/../bin/hbase: line 412: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java/bin/java: Not a directory
/home/mike/hbase-1.2.6/bin/../bin/hbase: line 412: exec: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java/bin/java: cannot execute: Not a directory
starting regionserver, logging to /home/mike/hbase-1.2.6/bin/../logs/hbase-mike-1-regionserver-mike-thinks.out
/home/mike/hbase-1.2.6/bin/../bin/hbase: line 412: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java/bin/java: Not a directory
/home/mike/hbase-1.2.6/bin/../bin/hbase: line 412: exec: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java/bin/java: cannot execute: Not a directory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not `JAVA_HOME`

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/
```

This is

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-version/bin/
```

---

Folow this steps:

1. Download `JRE` from [Oracle site](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) and unzip it
2. Open terminal window and type

   ```
   sudo apt-get install mc
   ```
3. After installation type

   ```
   sudo mc
   ```
4. From terminal window copy downloaded and unzipped `JRE` into the folder

   ```
   /usr/lib/jvm/java-version/
   ```
5. Open file

   ```
   /etc/bash.basrc
   ```
6. Add this lines to the end

   ```
   JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-version/bin

   export JAVA_HOME

   PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME

   export PATH
   ```
7. To check `JAVA_HOME` is set properly run this command

   ```
   echo $JAVA_HOME
   ```

---

**P.S.** Change line 412 in your `java-start.sh`

```
/bin/java
```

to

```
java
```

(and the same lines too, if exists)

Answer (score 0):

You can define all of the environment variables specifically for HBase using the configuration script `conf/hbase-env.sh`. There is the line where the `JAVA_HOME` parameter is set. Usually, this line is commented, but you can uncomment it and set the value as you need.

Using this way you don't need to change the common configuration on your system.